# Auto sync a specific directory daily on multiple computers that are on different networks

Tags: ubuntu, automation, synchronization

I am trying to have one directory be update 20 or more machines every night. Most of these machines are located at different locations and are on different networks.  All of the computers are running Ubuntu.

Ideally I would like to push the directory somewhere and every night some system will pull the directory to all 20 or so machines. I would like to try and use something like Git.

The directory path is the same on all of the machines and the same two file are being updated.

/home/username/folder

Comment: Hi! This question is off-topic on SO as it has nothing to do with Git's _usage,_ instead, it's about what sysadmins do: backing up stuff. So please consider asking this over there at https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also note that the wording "something like Git" hints at that the directory you want synched is not a Git repository, that is, you want to merely use Git as a means for synchronization. This is certainly doable but nevertheless this may be of dubious utlilty as there exist tools which are fine with synchronizing stuff w/o resorting to version control systems: `rsync`, `duplicity`, `unison`, `rclone`, `syncthing` — to name just a few.

Comment: (I'd just use `rsync` via SSH, having first set up pubkey-based authentication for SSH on the target hosts; but we're digressing from the on-topic even further.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropbox clone for ubuntu called sparkleshare. I think it uses git as it's engine.
The answer above (using rsync via SSH) is likely the fastest and cleanest solution.
Another option might be to add a line in cron to cd into the /home/username/folder and do a

```
git pull origin master
```

or create a simple bash or python script that will do this and put it as a daily cron job.